# Why is file not being imported - testing VueJS with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I've gotten the basic setup for unit testing VueJS with Jest configured, and have successfully tested other components in a similar fashion, but for one particular file I'm importing the file to be tested and it's being logged as undefined.

```
/* Test */

import transition from '@/components/mixins/transition'
/* The '@' aliases the src directory which has been validated 
for other components */

describe('transition mixin', () => {
   it('should invoke transition correctly', () => {
      console.log('transition: ', transition) 
      /* logs transition: undefined when suite is run */
   })
})
```

Directory structure:

```
src
-components
--mixins
---transition.js
```

This is what transitions.js looks like:

```
/* transitions.js, not much to see here */
export const transition = {
   props: {...},
   computed: {...},
   methods: {...}
}
```

Here is the jest.conf.js file although there's nothing here (to me) that suggests the transition.js mixin file to be tested would be excluded:

```
/* jest.conf.js */

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  browser: true,
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
     '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  transform: {
     '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
     '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/unit/coverage',
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/router/index.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ]
}
```

Comment: You either have to do a named import, i.e. `import { transition } from ... @/components/mixins/transitions';`; or, a default export, i.e. `export default transition = { ... };`. Right now, you probably have no default export in your "transition.js" and the default import `import transition from '@/components/mixins/transitions'` will correctly result in transition being `undefined`.

Comment: You are correct, changing it to `import { transition } from ...` resolved the issue, thank you.